# Require soap envelope example of how to add more than one record to a data extension object

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud

Require soap envelope example of how to add more than one record to a data extension object.

Only examples that I can find show how to add one record to a data extension object. E.g.  https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to contain each record in separate object elements. For example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6421ac0b-a454-42a3-99f7-a77ace024446">
                <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options/>
            <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <CustomerKey>0505A0A4-88AB-4FCA-AAC5-4873CD3C069B</CustomerKey>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>CustomerID</Name>
                        <Value>9999</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FirstName</Name>
                        <Value>Sandra</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>LastName</Name>
                        <Value>Sample</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>City</Name>
                        <Value>Melbourne</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>ID</Name>
                        <Value>9999</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Objects>
            <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <CustomerKey>0505A0A4-88AB-4FCA-AAC5-4873CD3C069B</CustomerKey>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>CustomerID</Name>
                        <Value>10000</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FirstName</Name>
                        <Value>Sam</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>LastName</Name>
                        <Value>Sample</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>City</Name>
                        <Value>Melbourne</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>ID</Name>
                        <Value>10000</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```